# Is it true that first line of Javascript will be executed only after all script tags with src attribute are downloaded and evaluated?

Tags: javascript, dom

By first line of Javascript I meant the JS code inside  tags with no "src" attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By right it will be evaluated top down.

Read more about it from my previous answer: [Load and execution sequence of a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page/1795502#1795502)

Let me explain here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(jQuery); // alerts jQuery's namespace
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

The result is alerting `undefined`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert(jQuery); // alerts jQuery's namespace
</script>
```

The result is alerting a object/function where defined.

Answer (score 1):

The scripts are executed in the order they are listed in the html. It does not matter if they are inline JavaScript (within `<script>` tags) or if loaded as external scripts (`<script src="xx.js">`).