# Javascript execution access points in a document

Tags: javascript, interpreter

I'm wondering, where the script interpretation starts in a document with an iframe, that contains another document, with `"<header><script>"` or possibly  `"<body><script>"`. I just really need to ensure that the execution happens in the "outer" document before the iframe document, but it seems that it is random, is that right ?

BTW, what about the order of interpretation of referenced javascripts ? Does it depend on "where" in the document I reference it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just really need to ensure that the execution happens in the "outer" document before the iframe document

To do this with 100% certainty, you would have to create the iframe in the outer document's `DOMReady` event (e.g. with jQuery's `.ready()`). If you embed it directly into the document, there is indeed no guarantee of when the scripts will execute.

> what about the order of interpretation of referenced javascripts ? Does it depend on "where" in the document I reference it ?

Yes, script blocks get executed in the order they are in the page. Here is a great answer on the issue: [Load and execution sequence of a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page/1795502#1795502)

Comment: And can I just reference parent window functions from within the iframe and be safe ? parent.getWordCount( ) . If the execution starts in the iframe <script> and there will be a function reference to global function that is declared in parent <script> that is to be executed later, is it gonna be "undefined" or the interpreter finds it additionally ?

Comment: @Iisak if you are not loading the script afterwards dynamically, you should be fine this way: All functions from the parent document should be available in the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends **how** you inject the Javascript (in the parent document and the `<iframe>`) and **where** you inject it.

If for instance, you use **dynamic script insertion** in your parent document, but **blocking** `<script>` tags in your iframe code, the iframe script will probably get executed first.

The pitfall can be if you put your `<script>` tags at the bottom of your parent document but the `<iframe>` somewhere above.

So in general, if you use blocking `<script>` tags before you actually create the `<iframe>` in your parent document, this "**should**" execute first. But then again cutting edge browser will try to load those scripts in parallel mode which also could lead to a wrong behavior there.

You should create the `<iframe>` dynamically on the `DOMContentLoaded` or `onload` window event in your parent document.

Comment: What I'm sure about is that blocking <script> tags in iframe header section get executed before any blocking <script> tags anywhere in parent document <body>, no matter where. In all chrome & firefox at least... I'm surprised that there is not standard definition of this behavior, so that browsers can stick to it

Comment: But what annoys me is that blocking <script> from iframe <body> element are executed before scripts inserted from parent document's header section...this is really ugly behavior