# How to ensure YUI object to be created first

Tags: javascript, yui3

I like YUI sandbox but I have a problem with it. Consider a document with an iframe (for instance ckedior that I included) with an initialization script. It is always executed before the outer document's  sections (don't know why).

And I need to call a function, that is initialized in YUI sandbox in the parent document. But it can never be initialized, because the execution starts in the iframe.

```
var getWordCount;

AUI().ready('aui-node', 'console', function(A) {

    getWordCount = function (htmlData) {
        var target = A.one('div.my-png-image');
        target.one('div:fist-child').set('text', strip(htmlData).trim().split(/\s+/).length);
    };
});
```

Without yui sandbox I'd just declared a function in the parent document, and even tough the execution starts in the iframe, the global function would exist and could be called from the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be AUI.ready, as it executes only when the whole HTML is loaded. This means the iFrame would load before the browser triggers the .ready-event.

You could try to test this by changing the AUI event you use to trigger your code, and put the code you want to run before the iFrame-load outside the AUI.ready.

If you need a certain element in dOM to be loaded before running, you could try checking if the element is loaded and then run your script, like [in this example](http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2006/04/12/element-ready/).

Comment: <script> in iframe is executed first, so that even YUI().use() is executed after the iframe script anyway. At least in Firefox, in chrome it is other way around. One just cannot rely on that. I was dealing with that in my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5076612/306488. And as to the element pre-loading suggestion, I cannot modify the iframe script, so that I can't preload any element... This is really a big disadvantage of yui sandboxing

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps create the IFrame from within the AUI().ready?