# Order of loading of assets in a page

Tags: html

Simple question.. if I have on my page:

```
<link .. with href to some css>
<script.. with src to some script>
```

can I expect that css will be loaded in page before script loaded and executed, or they can be loaded in parallel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define priority to load resources on the webpages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178863/how-to-define-priority-to-load-resources-on-the-webpages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The CSS will start load and parse, 
   The the script will start load and parse.
2. Then the script will execute after the load/parse is complete.

Comment: Script can start to execute before css parsed? I just want to be sure that executing of the script will start only when styles are ready.

Comment: No, it will PARSE prior (potentially) but not execute until after.

Comment: One "gotcha" is that IE through vers 9 will only load 32 CSS files IF you have a larger number in links.

Answer (score 1):

CSS will start loading before the script but loading will be asynchronous. So, you can't be sure which one will be loaded first (depending on the size and internet connection status at that moment) but both of them will be loaded when you reach the `onLoad()` event.