# Array Contents Through a Loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, image-gallery, preloading

I'm trying to preload all of the images in an image gallery and found a nice, simple piece of code that does that (first code sample).

I want to try and make the gallery as dynamic as possible. **Is there a way of looping through all of the images in the gallery so that all the images can be preloaded?**

First is the code for preloading all the images for reference.  Second is what I'm trying to work on.

```
// code for preloading images
var images = [
    'bigPics/1.jpg',
    'bigPics/2.jpg'
];

$(images).each(function() {
    var image = $('<img />').attr('src', this);
});
```

.

```
 // code I'm trying to re-work

    // this give me the number of images in the gallery
    var numberOfChildren = $(".thumb").length;

// then I want to loop through all of the images that make up the array as above and output???
    for (var i=0; i<numberOfChildren; i++)
      {
      var images = [ 'bigPics/' + i + '.jpg' ];
      }

    $(images).each(function() {
        var image = $('<img />').attr('src', this);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
$( '.thumb' ).each(function ( i ) {
    $( '<img>' ).attr( 'src', 'bigPics/' + i + '.jpg' );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like is explained in this SO question:
[Javascript load background-image asynchrously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206435/javascript-load-background-image-asynchrously)