# Most efficient position for background-image property in a style sheet

Tags: css, optimization, background-image

I am placing a large, non-repeating background image on my website using the CSS `background` property. Since the image is so large, it takes a long time for some connections to render the image.

Here is my CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background: url('large-image.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

I have already done the following to optimize the image for the web:

- Reduced it to the lowest possible resolution that does not compromise quality
- Changed the image type from a PNG to a JPEG
- Styled the page so that the content is readable even without the background image

My question: To further optimize the image loading time, would it make a difference if I put the `background` tag at the bottom of my style sheet? Or would the effect of this be negligible?

I tend to order my CSS by the hierarchy of my HTML, so the `#wrapper` styles are at the top of my style sheet. Does the order of properties in a style sheet make a noticeable impact on load time when the user has a slower connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What could affect *perceived* loading time is initial `#wrapper` availability - i.e. if at the time of the initial load it is not part of the page and is added with JS, the background image will not begin loading - but I doubt this would be a common scenario.

Background image loading does not affect domready handlers, however if you want to speed up background availability you could try the following:

```
#wrapper {
    background: url(large-image.png) no-repeat center center,
                url(small-image.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Multiple_backgrounds):

> With CSS3, you can apply multiple backgrounds to elements. These are
>   layered atop one another with the first background you provide on top
>   and the last background listed in the back. Only the last background
>   can include a background color.

What this does is effectively allows you to load a lower-res image as the bottom layer of the background, while the expensive hi-res image is still loading. Remember the good old times of `lowsrc`? That's the behaviour we're simulating. Note that both the low- and the hi-res image downloads begin simultaneously, so use this only if the large image is truly unbearably large.

Also: you're saying you've optimized the image; I still suggest you try [Yahoo SmushIt](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/), you'd be surprised how muich redundant data can be stripped from a PNG witout loss of quality (I currently have intermittent problems using their service, but it works after a few attempts, alternatively you could use [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) but imo it would be too much effort to set it up and configure for a single image)

### Update:

It has been suggested you wait for domready to fire and add your style using `$("#wrapper").css(...);`. What that does is add inline styling to an element, which would 1) interfere with selector specificity 2) only apply to this particular instance of `#wrapper` (bad if, say, it is part of ajax content coming from the server).

You could alternatively add a new css rule at runtime:

```
$('head').append('<style type="text/css">#wrapper {background: url(large-image.jpg) no-repeat center center;}</style>');
```

This would be organically added to document stylesheets and apply to all future instances of `#wrapper`, as well as not interfere with selector specificity. You still end up with a brief flash of unstyled content (before the handler is fired and the style is applied) so I don't advocate this approach.

Answer (score 4):

Location in the stylesheet will not affect the load time.

What you can do though is prevent it loading in some cases, such as on a cellphone.

For reference:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Those media queries aren't fail-proof, but they'll catch alot of the slower cases, which would generally be mobile devices.  On the other hand, if somebody is on a 56k modem with their desktop, I just don't know what to do about it (maybe they're used to it).

You can use Jquery and [waitforimages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) to ensure it loads after all other images, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500141/do-external-stylesheets-get-loaded-before-the-html).  The CSS stylesheet will be fully loaded and evaluated before the page is shown, so the location of your background-image CSS does not matter in the stylesheet.

If you want the image to only load once the rest of the content is displayed you could use jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#wrapper").css({'background-image':'url("large-image.jpg")', 'background-repeat':'no-repeat', 'background-position':'center center'});
});
```

Comment: what you're doing is adding inline styling to an element - this would 1) interfere with selector specificity 2) only apply to this particular instance of `#wrapper` which would be bad if, say, it is part of ajax content coming from the server. You could alternatively *add a new css rule* at runtime

Comment: @o.v. got it, thanks for the clarification and further explanation above.