# Async load CSS - Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, performance

I am using this for async loading the CSS file:

```
<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

, but the event doesn't bind in Firefox. In Chrome works fine and `preload` is changed to `stylesheet`.
In FF stays the same.

I have tried with `onload="console.log(90)">` and it binds in Chrome, but no in FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [preload specification](https://w3c.github.io/preload/) is only an Editor's Draft. It isn't standard. It should be considered experimental and not for production use.

[Firefox doesn't support it](https://caniuse.com/#search=preload) as standard (although you can turn it on in the browser's settings if you want to test its implementation).

Comment: I know it doesn't support. If you check the code you will see, that it uses onload event to change it to `stylesheet`, but this onload event doesn't bind in FF. This is what I am asking.

Comment: @gdfgdfg — It doesn't support preload. So it doesn't load it. Since it never loads it, the onload event won't fire.

Comment: Ok, but why this works in Chrome ? Also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46750893/5849229

Comment: Because Chrome **does** support preload! And the answer you link to **says** that it won't work in Firefox!

Comment: hm ok thanks. I was confused that it works on Chrome and forgot actually what onload means :) .