# Is a JavaScript function defined in <script> block accessible by another JS function?

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following code in my HTML file:

```
<script src = "js/create.js"></script>
<script>
    function show() {
              //some code here
    }
</script>
```

In the JavaScript file create.js, I want to call the function `show()` defined in the  block, like this:

```
//File create.js
var a = show();
```

So is the function `show()` accessible in the file create.js?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: it depends on **when** you access the function.

Comment: Sorry my code is actually much more complex than that. This is just an example. I can't test it easily since I'm writing JS code on mobile phone.

Comment: JavaScript has function scope, so as long as you don't declare it inside a function then any other script blocks can see it. There is no such thing as "script-block" scope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you defined the function without putting it in a var so it will be hoisted to the most outer scope being the global scope.
But you run create before that function is declared so it wont see it, turn them around and see.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Does the sequence of function definition matter in JavaScript? Sorry I'm a newbie of JavaScript.

Comment: I tried it and yes it works. The show() function can be found by create.js.

Answer (score 3):

You could have just tried this one out, but I'll still try to briefly explain.

Since JavaScript is client side, it depends on the current state of the client side. Until the needed part is loaded, you won't be able to access it.

In your case, you first include your create.js file. When it is loaded, the next one isn't yet. So `var a = show();` will look for the function named `show();` however will throw an error saying null reference to the function, as it wouldn't be available in client yet.

The way you can avoid this is to check whether the parts of the documents were loaded. In jQuery, this is made with `$(document).ready`, in classic JavaScript you can somewhat depend on `window.onload`, `body` tag's `onload`.

There is also another casual way of doing this, see the following sheet.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test!</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function show(){
      alert("Hey there!");
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Hey there!</h1>
  <p>The alert box should appear after these lines are loaded in client, this will also mean the head is completed, so it's safe to call the function show()</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      show();
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

In that, we can certainly assume the function defined in the head was loaded until the point the second script, which calls the defined function can be runnable safely.

Comment: Thanks. This will work. What is I switch the order of two <script> blocks like this:

<script>
    function show() {
              //some code here
    }
</script>
<script src = "js/create.js"></script>

Does this avoid the problem of not loading function show() in create.js?

Comment: That would also avoid the problem. Until the line where `create.js` is called, the needed function would have already been loaded. So yes, it would also work. However especially when you're making DOM changes, it's a must to have your scripts either after "document completed" sort of event catchers, or after your whole body content, before the tag is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is how add-in libraries like jQuery work. You include their .js file, and then call its methods.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, it is different because I want to refer a function in create.js where the function show() is defined below.

Comment: There tends to be more of an issue when javascript inadvertently references an HTML element that does not yet exist on the page. You might find [this excellent question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page) helpful.