# HTML/JS Execution Order

Tags: javascript, html, execution

I am trying to understand the Execution Order of HTML and JS functions.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script>

         function myFunction()
         {
            var x=document.getElementsByName("check1");
            x[0].disabled=true;
            x[0].checked=true;
            x[0].value="Y";
         }

         function myFunction1()
         {
            var x=document.getElementsByName("check1");
            alert(x[0].value);
         }

      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="myFunction()">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <form>
         <input type="checkbox" name="check1" unchecked enabled value="N"/>
         <input type="button" value="Button" onclick="myFunction1()"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Finally the element "check1" value is =Y.
finally checkbox is checked and disabled.
Can anyone explain about this.
I have already gone through this link which is very useful:
[Load and execution sequence of a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page)

Still the above example will help bit more .Thanks

Comment: Your function names are the same - myFunction(). You probably want to change one to myFunction1()

Comment: Why you have defined 2 functions named `myFunction`?

Answer (score 0):

first you change the name of functions.. it must be different. then the execuation order is

- first onbody load function is called then input button function called.
  you can even check it by alert that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you mean why your `checkbox` value is `'Y'` despite you disabled the checkbox.

disabling checkbox only make it inactive as far as User Interface is concerned but through script you can still change the value.

Comment: i have updated my quetion.can you tell why ment "check1" value is =Y at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The "myFunction()" method called in on load event so that it executed immediately after a page is loaded.  and the function "myFunction1()" called on button click event .And you are initializing check box value with "N"  value thats why it displaying n after every page load function