# How to include a external js file programmably and make sure it to be load before others?

Tags: asp.net

I have a base page , and all the pages are inherited from it . and different pages would load some external js files individually. Let's say one of these pages `AddUser.aspx`.

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page {
   ....
}

public partial class AddUser : BasePage {
   ....
}
```

After `AddUser.aspx` is rendered. The html content of it shows some js files would be included like below.

```
<script src="a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="d.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

I want to register an external js file before all these js file. Let's say it is named `firstrun.js` and make sure `firstrun.js` always firstly run before other js files in all the page.

the desired result like below.

```
<script src="firstrun.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="c.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="d.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

Is there any workaround in the base page ? thanks.

Comment: What is a "base page" and what happens if you just put the line on that place?

Comment: [This might help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page)

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks your review. I have updated the post .please review it again. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I find .NET's method of inserting JS files troublesome (particularly once you get into master pages where the page's relative path changes).

I don't think it's an elegant solution but the best way I've found of doing is to create a string literal.

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ScriptsLiteral" />
```

Then in your CS

```
this.Scripts.Text = string.Concat("<script src=\"", this.Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/MyScript.js"), "\"</script>");
```

By doing it this way you can guarantee where on your page the JS file will appear and that the link will be correct for any page in your site.

You can also use a GenericHtmlControl or a UserControl/Server Control to do the same thing.

Comment: If I didn't misunderstood you, Does it mean I need to add `<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ScriptsLiteral" />` in all my pages ? Is there any way to add it in the base page ? thanks.

Comment: I add it to a master page, if you're using a base page rather than a master page can you add it programmatically there?

Comment: So the problem turn to "How can I add a Literal as the first element of body programmatically ?" , Isn't it ?

Comment: @Joe.wang there are a number of ways to do it but it's very difficult to advise without seeing your pages (ideally the markup) - perhaps using a content placeholder in your head section?

Comment: Thanks your help. +1. I found a way to make it .please help to review it .thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Liath's answer and help.

I found a way to insert the specified js in the header. Please review it .

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
        {   
            //this.Page.Header is not ready. it is null. so I move it to PreRender
            base.OnPreInit(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            Literal tempLit = new Literal();
            tempLit.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + this.Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/firstrun.js") + "\"></script>";    
            this.Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0,tempLit);    
            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks sensible, I'd suggest using the Page.ResolveUrl() method though as it'll be more stable if your page is in a subdirectory

Comment: @Liath Good, Update it.