# How can I stop rendering HTML until external css, js loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I just want to stop rendering to the html to the DOM until my `Css` and `Js` loaded from an external source.

```
    <html is showing here >
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://preview.somex.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_mywinners/css/style.css">
           <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://preview.somex.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_mywinners/js/mywinners-global-scripts.js">
    <html is end here >
```

Why I'm doing this is the static html is looking ugly until the css and js loaded and then after sometime?(after loading css and js from network) it looks cool.

So I just want to stop showing html until the script and css load.

Any clues/help regarding this ?

Comment: Put the links in the head

Comment: @Smeegs nailed it; put the `link` and `script` tags in the `head` tag of the doc.

Comment: @Smeegs Thanks for the prompt reply. They are already in head. I'm guessing because of network those files are loading slowly.

Comment: That's odd, they should be blocking calls.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Post demo code or a link for us to test.

Comment: Create a wrapper of over content with display:none; once you check using document.ready() just change the wrapper style to `visible` also you can add "loading please wait.." div out of wrapper to make it more interactive.

Answer (score 0):

If your includes are nested in the BODY tag not a lot you can do with just pure HTML. If you can move them up into the HEAD section section this should fix itself. A great breakdown of how the page loads and what fires when is on an answer to another StackOverflow question see this link :

[Which is the load, rendering and execution order of elements in a HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083248/which-is-the-load-rendering-and-execution-order-of-elements-in-a-html-page)

Hope you find this helpful.