# Browser load priority: CSS or Javascript?

Tags: html, browser

After parsing HTML, browser parse the styles or javascript? Or it depends of the import sequence?

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts

Answer (score 1):

CSS and Javascript files are loaded and parsed as they are included in the HTML (or loaded by Javascript code)

Comment: So, if i need to ensure that styles are loaded first than script, the only way is moving the import statement before script import?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?