# How do I send a Javascript/CSS file that corresponds to the HTML document in HTTP?

Tags: html, css, http, browser, client-server

I actually do not want to implement that behaviour (and I never did) but I want to know how the process and the response-message/chain looks like when a client requests a html page from the server that has css and js files linked to it.

Will the browser parse the html document and look for links in it that he then requests seperately? I can't really think of a more practical way to do it. It would require the files to use relative urls though.

I couldn't find any information on that particular topic on internet for that so far... which really surprizes me.

Comment: I believe you can already find examples on StackOverflow. Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page

Comment: @light Thats exactly what I wanted to know! Sorry I somehow wasn't finding the right keywords to search for it seems :) Thanks!

Comment: No prob. :) Can a moderator please close this as a duplicate?