# How to call a function after executing all javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function which makes an external call to an API which in turn injects some HTML into my page.

Now i want to execute a function which checks this script and if it does not inject the HTML into my page i want to do something else here. The problem is i cannot call this function on `document.ready` nor `window.load` as the first script to the external API gets executed after these 2 events.

The script is something like below:

```
(function () {
    var o = ccs_cc_args; o.push(['_SKey', '35455c2f']); o.push(['_ZoneId', '311e740881']);
    var sc = document.createElement('script'); sc.type = 'text/javascript'; sc.async = true;
    sc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.cnetcontent.com/jsc/h.js';
    var n = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; n.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, n);
})();
```

Now the function I wrote is like below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if ($("#ccs-inline-content").html() == "") {
          $('#ProductDetails > ul li:has(a[href="#tabs-1"])').hide()
           $("#ProductDetails").tabs('refresh');
            $("#ProductDetails").tabs('option', 'active', 1);
        }
    });
```

So i need to force the second function to run after the first script which does not happen.

Comment: That's too confusing to understand as it is. Please create a MCVE (Read [ask])

Comment: Put both of them into the same $(document).ready(...) - and the upper one will run first. The accepted answer to this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#establish-script-block-source), after the executing a script, browsers must

> 6. [Fire a simple event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) named `afterscriptexecute` that bubbles (but is not cancelable) at the [`script`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element.
> 7. If the script is from an external file, [fire a simple event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) named `load` at the [`script`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element.
>
>    Otherwise, the script is internal; [queue a task](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) to [fire a
>      simple event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) named `load` at the [`script`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element.

So you can add a `load` or `afterscript` event listener to the `script` element:

```js
scriptElement.addEventListener('load', callback);
```

If you don't have a reference to the `script` element, you can use event delegation and add the event listener to an ancestor, e.g. `document`.

Note this will only work with `afterscriptexecute`, which bubbles, but not with `load`,  which doesn't.

Also note the event listener may run for multiple `script` elements, so you may have to filter the desired one.

```js
document.addEventListener('afterscriptexecute', function(e) {
  if(e.target.src === url)
    callback();
});
```

You can also use event delegation in the capture phase. Then both `afterscriptexecute` and `load` will work, and the chance that some other listener stops the propagation of the event (which would avoid the execution of the callback) will be lower.

```js
document.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'script' && e.target.src === url)
    callback();
}, true);
```

Comment: What will be the event for this function?

Comment: @MarsOne Not sure what you mean. It will be a [simple event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event).