# jQuery.ready() function and asynchronous CSS

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I want to load my website CSS asynchronously. I want to know if `jQuery.ready()` function will run after the async load of the CSS is completed or will jQuery ignore it and the CSS might finish loading after `jQuery.ready()` function starts running.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for window onload event???

Comment: If that's can solve my issue, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing [`$.holdReady()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdReady)

```js
// set `$.holdReady()` to `true`
$.holdReady(true);
// do stuff at `$.holdReady(true)`
// e.g., call hide `body` element
$("body").hide();
// load asynchronous `css`
$("<style>")
.appendTo("head")
.load("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/ec1ebbf8024850b7d400/"
      + "raw/906431c0472286e141b91aac1676369bbb8d2f97/style.css"
      , function(e) {
  // set `$.holdReady()` to `false`
  $.holdReady(false);
});
// do stuff at `$.holdReady(false)`
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").show();
  alert("ready");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body>
  <div>
    abc
  </div>
    <div>
    123
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no. `$(document).ready()` will not wait for asynchronous loading to finish. It will fire as soon as DOM is loaded.

Normally you would put `async` loading functions inside `(document).ready()` so they start executing as soon as they safely can. It's a little weird that you're trying to perform async CSS loading before the DOM. `$(document).ready()` is an event-trigger function. It's cannot be made to wait.

Please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

P.S. Please read this "execution sequence" answer:
[Load and execution sequence of a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page)

Comment: I want to load CSS asynchronously but want to run jquery code afterwards

Answer (score -1):

jQuery.ready() runs when the DOM has been loaded.

If you wish to load some CSS asynchronously, then your best bet would be to insert **link** tag in the head in the ready callback.

In other words...

```
<script language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
         $("head").append("<link rel=stylesheet href='yourfile.css' type='text/css'/>");
    }
   )
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think you have not read the question properly. He wants to load css async first and then document.ready should work.