# Why I cannot send php variable to javascript variable using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have javascript function using javascript variable from php variable using jQuery. The code is shown below:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($v1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
});
```

javascript function

```
function abc(){
alert(v1);
}
```

I cannot print out the value of v1, but when I do not use jquery to send php variable to javascript variable, I use the below code after $v1 in php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($v1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
</script>
```

And the function can print out value of v1.

But, I want to see which variables I have already used and see them at the top instead of at the bottom. So, I decide to use jquery but it fails. Where does it go wrong?

---

the second way which works for me is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
      function abc(){
      alert(v1);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT r_ID,r_cname,address FROM rest ORDER BY count2+count3 DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    array_push($name,$row["r_cname"]);
}
}
?>
    <script>
      var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($name); ?>;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why there are no encapsulation problems?

Comment: Change the extension of the file to `.php`

Comment: Your `alert(v1)` needs to be inside the same function the `var v1 = ...` is in. And the JSON needs to be valid to print out the valid object.

Comment: specify where is your all code is exist ? in which files ?

Comment: Little Phild, the file has already been set as .php

Comment: LearningMode, the code is put in the same file let's say abc.php

Comment: Daniel Cheung, So, how to change it?
Also, why does the code work when I put <script type="text/javascript">
var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($v1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
</script> after $v1 in php?

Comment: @KeroroChan have given the ans , try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `alert(v1)` needs to be inside the same function the `var v1 = ...` is in. And the JSON needs to be valid to print out a valid object.

A PHP printed variable often need **not** to be in jQuery. It almost certainly not need to be inside a jQuery function, trust me, because it is often just a piece of data.

I always use this method/practice:

```
<?php
//My businesses
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    ...
    <head>
        <script>
            //By the way, HTML5 don't require you to state the type of script, it is defaulted to JavaScript.
            var x = <?php echo json_encode($x, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);?>
        </script>
        <script>
            //Rest of my code
            $(function(){
                //My jQuery here
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

### Why declaring the variable inside jQuery "doesn't" work

It does, but outside the scope of `$(function(){})`, no one can access variables defined inside. It is a basic mechanism of JS. On the other hand, the `function(){}` inside `$()` is an **argument**, that is the second reason it doesn't work getting the value outside.

Example:

```
var a = 3;

function(){
    var b = 4;
    a; //<-- 3
};

b; //<-- undefined
```

### Why the second script worked

Let's assume your code looks like this:

```
...
<script>
    var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($v1, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);?>
</script>
...
<script>
    $(function(){
        v1; //There is a value
    })
</script>
...
```

Because your new `v1` variable is defined just under `<script>`, it is a **global variable**. A global variable can be accessed anywhere on the webpage.

In contrast, a **local variable** cannot be accessed outside the scope it is in. Look at this tree diagram:

```
window
|- v1
`- function x
   |- v2
   `- function y
      `- v3
```

Basically, a variable can only be accessed by its children and never its parents. So:

`v1` can be accessed inside inside and outside of `function x` and `function y` but `v2` can only be accessed inside of `function x` and `function y` and `v3` can only be accessed inside `function y`

Here is a table of what variables can be accessed where:

```
   globally | function x | function y
------------|------------|-----------
v1     ✓    |      ✓     |     ✓
------------|------------------------
v2          |      ✓     |     ✓
------------|------------------------
v3          |            |     ✓
```

### Final answer

You just need to do this: `<script>var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($v1);?></script>` before you use the variable on your webpage.

Comment: why does the code work when I put <script type="text/javascript"> var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($v1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>; </script> after $v1 in php? It seems that the encapsulation will happen for this code.

Comment: I just simply my question. Actually, I need to do many stuffs to get $x in php. So, it is hard to implement using your method.

Comment: @KeroroChan Sorry, I don't really understand your reply :/ Do you speak Chinese? You just need to do this: `<script> var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($v1);?> </script>` before you use the variable on your webpage..

Comment: I have updated my second way which works for me but I don't want to put <script> var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($v1);?> </script> at the bottom. But, why there are no encapsulation problems?

Comment: @KeroroChan You don't have to put that at the bottom. The `<script>` tag can be places in the `<head>` or `<body>`. Yo don't even need to put the JS + PHP code in an isolated tag. Just place the line of code somewhere globally.

Comment: @KeroroChan Regarding the "encapsulation problem". You see, the browser only scans the code inside the `<script>` tag to send to the JS engine. It does not regards whether or not the code is isolates. JS in HTML is not like classes in C#.

Comment: You mean that     <script> var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($name); ?>;
  </script> is in <body> which is the same scope as $name?

Comment: @KeroroChan no, you have to understand, that you don't regard PHP and JS together. PHP only prints out the text for JS to process, they don't know each other. I'm talking about **scope** in JavaScript :)

Comment: I don't want to separate the php code and put it at the top. The same reason why I want to put the javasript variable at the top is I don't want the javascript variables separated. However, you put the php code at the top and the php code is separated instead of javascript code.

Comment: @KeroroChan You don't need to. Do you prefer me explaining in Chinese? If you think it is more readable?

Comment: You mean that v1 in $(document).ready(function(){
var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($v1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
}); can only be used in  $(document).ready(function(){ } and cannot be used in other javascript functions because of different scope?

Comment: @KeroroChan no, the basic problem revolving your question be "JS scope understanding". You cannot access a higher scope from a lower/local scope. The one that changes scope in JS is mainly (I say this because I am not too certain if there is another way to change scope) `function(){}`

Comment: If I have to put php code at the top, I prefer to put the script at the end. Thank you for explaining the scope problem.

Comment: @KeroroChan If you are still not sure, you're welcome to ask more! :)

Comment: @KeroroChan Also, I need to stress that there is no restraints on where to put PHP and JS code. FYI, here is my answer to "Where to put JS libraries on a webpage". The same goes to "code" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702909/where-to-insert-javascript-libraries-and-css-in-my-html-code/34703110#34703110

Comment: Thank you, Daniel Cheung

Comment: Daniel Cheung, do you have facebook,etc? If I have problems, I want to ask you first.

Comment: @KeroroChan I don't want to disclose my Facebook, besides, I'm not that good either. If you ask on StackOverflow, you might get an answer faster :) People here are friendly (if you don't frustrate them with hard to understand questions and show that you have researched but to no avail)

Comment: OK! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lays in timing and/or scope.

This code will run after the page is done loading and all the variables declared in it are encapsulated and exist only within it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){...})
```

Try this:

```
// Declaring variable in global scope.
var v1 = <?php echo json_encode($v1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

$(document).ready(function(){

    // Open console to view result
    console.log(v1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working, follow the sequence

```
<?php
    $v1 = ["a","b","c"];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
v1 = <?php echo json_encode($v1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
abc();
function abc(){
    alert(v1);
}
</script>
```

------------------- Updated code if js is before php code  ----------------------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    v1 = $("#v1").val();
    abc();
    function abc(){
        alert(v1);
    }
});
</script>
<?php
    $v1 = ["a"=>"aa","b"=>"bb","c"=>"cc"];
    $v1_json = json_encode($v1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
<input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $v1_json; ?>' id="v1">
```

Comment: I don't want the script after php.

Comment: @KeroroChan have updated my code hope you want something like this ?

Comment: It may work but it has too much overhead like <input type="hidden" value='<?php echo $v1_json; ?>' id="v1">. But, thanks for your answer.