# AngularJS app not loading

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to make a simple AngularJS app:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        Order by column:    <select ng-model="columnName">
                                <option value="+name">Name ASC</option>
                                <option value="age">Age ASC</option>
                                <option value="-salary">Salary DESC</option>
                            </select>
        <br/>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | orderBy:columnName">
                    <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.age }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>
                    **<td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>**
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    var employees1 = [
        {name: 'Jim', age: 18, salary: 4500, DOB: new Date("November 18th, 2009")},
        {name: 'Joe', age: 18, salary: 4000, DOB: new Date("November 18th, 2012")},
        {name: 'Bob', age: 20, salary: 6000, DOB: new Date("November 18th, 2004")},
        {name: 'Rob', age: 45, salary: 1800, DOB: new Date("November 18th, 2001")}
    ]; 

    $scope.employees = employees1;
    $scope.columnName = '+name'; 
}]);
```

EDIT:

I added the Date objects in my employee array and when I try to print them out in the ng-repeat in the tr it keeps giving me null for the date column:
[image]

Comment: Have a look in your console for errors..

Comment: oh I don't even know why I didn't think of that... The console says: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/$injector/unpr?p0=orderbyFilterProvider%20%3C-"<!-- ngRepeat: employee in employees | orderby:'columnName' -->"rderbyFilter

Comment: You have a typo. It must be `orderBy` not `orderby`. Also mention the name of the key instead of `columnName`

Comment: Just realized that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `''` from orderBy

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | orderBy :columnName">
```

If you use `''`,it'll consider as property name rather then model.

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/fgct1kaa/)**</kbd>

Comment: But I did a two way data binding for columnName using ng-model in the select HTML element

Comment: Also I had one more quick question. Does the HTML get loaded first and then JS when the webpage is loaded?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page check this . I think you'll get your answer :) @KB3

Comment: Hi can you please take a look at my edit. I came across another problem with the date objects displaying null...

Comment: @KB3 provide your latest html or edit fiddle and provide me the link

Comment: user3141852 helped me figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Like previous answers, change the typo in "**orderBy**" filterProvider.

For date object (null value), the problem in data you gave,

```
var employees1 = [
    {name: 'Jim', age: 18, salary: 4500, DOB: new Date("November 18th, 2009")},
    {name: 'Joe', age: 18, salary: 4000, DOB: new Date("November 18th, 2012")},
    {name: 'Bob', age: 20, salary: 6000, DOB: new Date("November 18th, 2004")},
    {name: 'Rob', age: 45, salary: 1800, DOB: new Date("November 18th, 2001")}
];
```

**new Date("November 18th, 2001")** is wrong inside date function you passed the string as wrong (**18th** only need to give 18). Because of this, while converting to date it's giving null value.

So for please refer the date function and date format in java script. [refer this link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) . Convert to whatever format you want to display.