# HTML link to external javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I was basically implementing this from W3School:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol

I tried making the javascript into a separate file called accordion.js

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

and tried calling the javascript file via HTML doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="accordion.js"></script>
```

Can anyone tell me what I can do to fix this and help explain why it didn't work?

Comment: Is the JS file in the same directory as the HTML file?

Comment: Add your script just before end of body or add `window.addEventListener('load', function(){})`

Comment: Is the script tag in the body *after* the element `accordion`?

Comment: do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Thx Rico yeah I didn't place the script tag after accordion

Comment: Works now thx for all the suggestions guys :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load and execution sequence of a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a little more to the answer given in the comments :

Here is a long answer on the subject : [Load and execution sequence of a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page).

But, if we simplify, the parsing of the HTML is synchronous. The browser needs to parse the HTML before he can access the `DOM` via `javascript`, in your case:
`var acc=document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");`

That is why, and to prevent bugs like you had, that `$(document).ready()` from `jQuery` is very famous https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what errors you might be getting it sounds like it's likely the JS file isn't in the same directory.