# why is this 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm just trying to understand why 'z' comes back as undefined.

```js
var z = functionWithParameters(4, 3);
function functionWithParameters(x, y) {
    if (typeof z !== 'undefined') {
        document.getElementById("functionWithParameters").innerHTML = z;
        console.log('inside function: ' + z);
        console.log('inside function: z is a ' + typeof z);
    }
    console.log('before return: z = ' + z);
    return x * y;    
}
console.log('outside function: z = ' + z);
```

```html
    <p id = "functionWithParameters"></p>
    <script>
        functionWithParameters(4, 3);
    </script>
```

If I run the code as is, without commenting anything, it results with:

```
before return: z = undefined
outside function: z = 12
inside function: 12  
inside function: z is a number  
before return: z = 12
```

If I removed: if (typeof z !== 'undefined'), the code results with:

```
inside function: undefined
inside function: z is a undefined
before return: z = undefined
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null[Learn More] (from Firefox),
```

and the line: console.log('outside function: z = ' + z); does not execute. I though may this was because the function has a return statement, but commenting out the return did not change the results.

Any help with understanding this would be awesome.
Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: My guess is var hoisting. Thus, `z` isn't given a value and is undefined.

Comment: logic makes no sense. How can a variable that is dependent on return of a function be defined inside that function?

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know about this example but it makes sense in recurrence relation algorithm.

Comment: This probably does not matter, but I wrote my function using this page as a reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: Know about undefined https://codepen.io/grumpy/post/undefined-scope-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1795502/2008285) answer to the question on an order in which DOM is loaded / executed.

You wrote:

> If I removed: if (typeof z !== 'undefined'), the code results with [..]
>   and the line: console.log('outside function: z = ' + z); does not execute. I though may this was because the function has a return statement, but commenting out the return did not change the results.

That's because you execute `functionWithParameters` function before `p` tag is loaded which results in `document.getElementById("functionWithParameters")` throwing an error simply because the `p` tag you are trying to find doesn't exist at the time.

Comment: @charlietfl It's not the function execution placed after `p` tag that is throwing this error. It's the script he posted after it which must have been executed before `p` tag was loaded.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. It makes sense now, and I think I should have realized what was happening.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for all the feedback. It was all useful but, for me, this answer and the link LineK provided was most helpful.

Comment: I've booked marked this link in case I need to reference it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null[Learn More] (from Firefox)
```

The function is throwing an exception, so `z` can never get a value. The reason for this exception is that you're trying to access an element before the document has finished loading.

A simple way of fixing this, is to load put the scripts at the bottom of the html file (before `</body>`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand  function execution flow.

```
        var z = functionWithParameters(4, 3);
        //call functionwithParamarters,and run into function body, 
        //at this time the value of z is undefined, 
        //the if statement block  is not executed,then output z is undefined. 
        //after call functionWithParameters ,z is 12
        function functionWithParameters(x, y) {
            if (typeof z !== "undefined") {
                document.getElementById("functionWithParameters").innerHTML = z;
                console.log('inside function: ' + z);
                console.log('inside function: z is a ' + typeof z);
            }
            console.log('before return: z = ' + z);
            return x * y;
        }
        console.log('outside function: z = ' + z);
        //at this line z is 12
        functionWithParameters(10, 10);
        //z still is 12 , calling functionWithParameters dont change value of z
        //and  if statement block is executed.
```

Answer (score -1):

You set variable `z`'s value as  `functionWithParameters`'s return value.
So, before function `functionWithParameters` returns a value,
the variable `z`'s value is undefined. This is
because it didn't get any value before the function `functionWithParameters` returns a value.

The reason the `console.log` doesn't work is
because your script has an active error and your script has to stop.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer. Z = the return value of function "functionWithParemters" therefore z Is undefined until functionWithParemters returns a value.

Comment: So, z is undefined until the return statement executes. And inside the function, z shows as undefined for the same reason.

I was also loading the javascript in the HTML head tag. Should I load it in the body instead?

Comment: @Tony That's what I meant in my answer, your code executes before `p` tag is loaded so it doesn't exist at first function run, you will understand it once you read through the answer I linked in my answer.

Comment: The script needs to under the p tag that you want to use. So yes, put the script in the body.  <p></p><script> //YOIR CODE HERE </script>

Comment: wow.. i'm new one in this community. And i think this commumity is very cool