# Basic error Scope JQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have a function, that call another function from index.js file. Why show this error?

```
<!-- page js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/index.js')}}" ></script> 
<script>
  function onedevice(imei) {
    // mostramos las graficas, se desean datos
    $('#charts_device1').show();
    $('#charts_device2').show();

    // rellenamos los datos
    // var imei = $("#select_imeis").val();
    if (imei !== 0) {
      load_chart_device(imei); // < this line
    }
  }
</script>
```

The error is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: load_chart_device is not defined
>        at onedevice (report_devices:302)
>        at HTMLDocument. (report_devices:234)
>        at mightThrow (jquery-3.2.1.js:3583)
>        at process (jquery-3.2.1.js:3651)

I change my code in index.js. But still not working.

```
function load_chart_device(imei){

console.log(imei);

//CODE....
 });




 function onedevice(imei){
 // mostramos las graficas, se desean datos

 $('#charts_device1').show();
 $('#charts_device2').show();
 // rellenamos los datos
 // var imei = $("#select_imeis").val();
 if(imei!==0){
    load_chart_device(imei);
  }
```

}

Comment: how's you are calling `onedevice()`?

Comment: Where is `load_chart_device()` defined?

Comment: The way I see it, your function `load_chart_device` is not in scope. This means that it is not defined anywhere when it is called in `onedevice`. Are you defining that function yourself, or is it some external code?

Comment: Hi. I Calling load_chart_device in index.js. 
I calling onedevice in the html,

 <script>
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                    onedevice({{$device->imei}});
                                 });
                                </script>

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because function `onedevice()` is executing first. Write importing of `index.js` inside html head tag

Write your `index.html` like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var imei = 10;

        function onedevice(imei) {
            // code ...
            if (imei !== 0) {
                load_chart_device(imei);
            }
        }

        // call onedevice
        onedevice(imei);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and write your `index.js` like this

```
function load_chart_device(imei) {
    console.log("load_chart_device is working fine");
    alert(imei);
}
```

Make sure you have imported `index.js` inside `<head></head>` tag.

To know further about how it works please read [Load and execution sequence of web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page)

Comment: I changed the call to onedevice(), and put the files in head of the document, but not working.