# manage to download file dependency in html page

Tags: javascript, html, server

I have a html page with couple of links to css & js files such as following..

```
<link href="file1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="file2.js"></script>
```

My problem is that most browsers concurrently start many connections to the server to download the included files, and it will choke my weak server (small micro controller).

My question is, how can I force the browser to download the files one after another in my page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page

Comment: @SimonJensen Both links are relevant, but neither answer the question.  The OP needs to know how to download CSS files synchronously, which is not answered in those questions - just discussed.